# getting external web page with in another mobile web site/ mobile web page

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I am trying to create a web page where a fixed download button at bottom and top area calling another page which has link, when i click the link, it will take to external webpage. where i call it with either div or an object. tried with iframe, but the links within the external page is not able to click.

please some one help me.

```
<div id="siteloader"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#siteloader")
        .html('<object data="h2.htm" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>');
    </script>
      <div id="downloadButton"> 
        <input id="dbutton" type="submit" src="download.png" value="" alt="Submit" />
      </div>
```